# Get the cars that passed specific cameras

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

**MYSQL/MARIADB Schema and sample data:**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `puzzle` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

USE `puzzle`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `event`;

CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `eventId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sourceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'think of source as camera',
  `carNumber` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 5849',
  `createdOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventId`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `event` (`eventId`, `sourceId`, `carNumber`, `createdOn`) VALUES
    (1, 44, '4456', '2016-09-20 20:24:05'),
    (2, 26, '26484', '2016-09-20 20:24:05'),
    (3, 5, '4456', '2016-09-20 20:24:06'),
    (4, 3, '72704', '2016-09-20 20:24:15'),
    (5, 3, '399606', '2016-09-20 20:26:15'),
    (6, 5, '4456', '2016-09-20 20:27:25'),
    (7, 44, '72704', '2016-09-20 20:29:25'),
    (8, 3, '4456', '2016-09-20 20:30:55'),
    (9, 44, '26484', '2016-09-20 20:34:55'),
    (10, 26, '4456', '2016-09-20 20:35:15'),
    (11, 3, '72704', '2016-09-20 20:35:15'),
    (12, 3, '399606', '2016-09-20 20:44:35'),
    (13, 26, '4456', '2016-09-20 20:49:45');
```

I want to get CarNumber(s) that have sourceId = 3 AND (26 OR 44) during 20:24 to 20:45. the query need to be fast since the real table contains over 300 million records.

so far below is the maximum i could go with the query (its not even producing valid results)

```
select * from event e where 
e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:45:00' 
and e.sourceId IN(3,26,44) group by e.carNumber;
```

the correct results for the provided data:

```
carNumber
4456
72704
```

I am really puzzled and stuck. i tried EXISTS, Joins, sub-query without luck, so I wonder if SQL is able to solve this question or should I use backend coding?

MySQL / MariaDB version in use:

mariadb-5.5.50

mysql-5.5.51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this to be fast, then the following *might* work, assuming you have an index on `event(createdOn, carNumber, SourceId)`:

```
select e.carNumber 
from event e 
where e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:45:00'
group by e.carNumber
having sum(e.sourceId = 3) > 0 and
       sum(e.sourceId IN (26, 44)) > 0;
```

I would be inclined to change this to:

```
select e.carNumber 
from event e 
where e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:45:00' and
      e.sourceId in (3, 26, 44)
group by e.carNumber
having sum(e.sourceId = 3) > 0 and
       sum(e.sourceId IN (26, 44)) > 0;
```

And then for performance, even this:

```
select carNumber
from ((select carNumber, sourceId
       from event e
       where e.sourceId = 3 and
             e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:45:00'
      ) union all
      (select carNumber, sourceId
       from event e
       where e.sourceId = 26 and
             e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:45:00'
      ) union all
      (select carNumber, sourceId
       from event e
       where e.sourceId = 44 and
             e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:45:00'
      )
     ) e
group by e.carNumber
having sum(e.sourceId = 3) > 0 and
       sum(e.sourceId IN (26, 44)) > 0;
```

This version can take advantage of an index on `event(sourceId, createdOn, carNumber)`.  Each subquery should use this index very effectively, bringing a small'ish amount of data together for the final aggregation.

Comment: I can't use indexing, since Insertion got higher priority in the project, about 200 records inserted per second and the real table contain much more columns. btw, 2nd query worked faster ~ 20% than 1st query which identical to @juergend's

Comment: regarding 3rd query, since i am not using indexes, it took over double time compared with 2nd query :(

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh . . . The third query is *specifically* formulated to use indexes as described in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do the trick for you:

```
 SELECT carNumber
 FROM event
 WHERE sourceID = 3
     AND carNumber IN (SELECT carNumber FROM event WHERE sourceID IN(26,44))
 GROUP BY carNumber
```

That WHERE clause looks for records with a `sourceID` of `3` and then also makes sure that the `carnumber` has at least one other record in the table where the `sourceid` is either `26` or `44`

Don't code anything outside of SQL for this one since this is definitely a problem that SQL is built to solve as quickly as possible.

Comment: your query took about ~25% extra time over @juergen d query. but it gave valid results. thanks.

Comment: Excellent. My assumption was that @juergend's would be faster. It was a race between multiple table scans versus single table scan with aggregation. I wonder if the results would change if you indexed on both sourceid, carnumber, and date..

Comment: one more point, on the real data, your query returned different results than juergend's and @Gordon, I don't know why, your query returned 209 cars, while other answers returned 59 cars. I can't share real data since its huge and against terms.

Comment: My query doesn't include the date range and it would be important to put the date range in both the main query and the subquery, which is when the indexing on date, carnumber, and sourceid would really shine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `having` clause to filter on groups. Use `sum()` to count how many times certains conditions are present in a group of data

```
select e.carNumber 
from event e 
where e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:24:00' 
  and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:45:00'
group by e.carNumber
having sum(e.sourceId = 3) > 0
   and sum(e.sourceId IN (26,44)) > 0
```

Comment: if @Gordon didn't come up with faster query, I would mark yours as answer, great job.

Answer (score 1):

**Shrink the table size**

With 300M rows, you should really use the smallest datatypes that are practical.

- `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes; `INT UNSIGNED` (only 4 bytes) is usually sufficient (max of 4 billion).  If fewer than 65K cameras, use a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.
- `carNumber` looks like a number, so why use `VARCHAR`?  The examples you have are taking 5-7 bytes in `VARCHAR`, would fit in 4 bytes with `INT UNSIGNED` or 3 bytes with `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (max of 16M).

Shrinking the table will help any solution chosen.

**Covering index**

This has already been suggested in other answers, but I want to make it clear why it helps.  If all the columns exist in a single query, the query can be performed in the index's BTree, without touching the data.  This is usually faster due to being smaller.  A 'covering' index for this query has `source_id, car_number, createdOn` in any order.

**Order of columns in index**

Since an index can only be used left-to-right the order is important.  (This does not apply to Gordon's first select, which needs `createdOn` first.)

1. `sourceId` is handled with `=` or `IN`, so it should come first.  In the case of `IN`, you probably need 5.6 or later to get the IN optimizations.
2. `createdOn` is a range, so the lookup will stop with it.
3. For "covering", now any extra columns can be added on.  In this case, `carNumber`.

So, most (not all) suggestions want this order: `INDEX(sourceId, createdOn, carNumber)`.

**Get rid of auto_increment**

Do you use `eventID` in other tables?  If so, then you should probably keep it.  If not, then is the combo `(sourceId, createdOn, carNumber)` unique?  If so, then make that the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Surrogate PK is nice for some situations, but it hinders performance in others.  I am suggesting that it *may* be a hindrance here.

**Avoid slow operations**

`UNION` usually involves a temp table; this adds overhead.  While `UNION` is beneficial in making better use of indexes, and avoiding `OR`, the overhead of the tmp table may outweigh the benefits for what seems to be a small resultset.

Gordon was right to use `UNION ALL` instead of the default `UNION DISTINCT`; the latter needs a de-dup pass, which is unnecessary for his query.

**Bottom Line**

1. Shrink the table.
2. Change the PK if possible; if not, add the suggested index.
3. Upgrade to at least 5.6
4. Use Gordon's second query.

**Another solution**

(I don't know if this is better, but it might be worth a try.)

```
SELECT carNumber 
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT carNumber
           FROM event
           WHERE sourceId = 3
             AND createdOn >= '2016-09-20 20:24:00'
             AND createdOn  < '2016-09-20 20:45:00'
         ) AS x
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM event
            WHERE carNumber = x.carNumber
              AND sourceId IN (26,44)
              AND createdOn >= '2016-09-20 20:24:00'
              AND createdOn  < '2016-09-20 20:45:00'
                 );
```

It would need two indexes:

```
(sourceId, createdOn, carNumber)  -- as before
(carNumber, sourceId, createdOn)  -- to optimize the EXISTS
```