# Get the cars that passed specific cameras based on individual search criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600514/get-the-cars-that-passed-specific-cameras) question but it differs because date time is different for each search filter.

**MYSQL/MARIADB Schema and sample data:**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `puzzle` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

USE `puzzle`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `event`;

CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `eventId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sourceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'think of source as camera',
  `carCode` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: A',
  `carNumber` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: 5849',
  `createdOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventId`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `event` (`eventId`, `sourceId`, `carCode`, `carNumber`, `createdOn`) VALUES
    (1, 44,'A', '4456', '2016-09-20 20:24:05'),
    (2, 26,'B', '26484', '2016-09-20 20:24:05'),
    (3, 5,'A', '4456', '2016-09-20 20:24:06'),
    (4, 3,'C', '72704', '2016-09-20 20:24:15'),
    (5, 3,'D' ,'399606', '2016-09-20 20:26:15'),
    (6, 5, 'A', '4456', '2016-09-20 20:27:25'),
    (7, 44,'C', '72704', '2016-09-20 20:29:25'),
    (8, 3,'A' ,'4456', '2016-09-20 20:30:55'),
    (9, 44,'B' ,'26484', '2016-09-20 20:34:55'),
    (10, 26,'B' ,'4456', '2016-09-20 20:35:15'),
    (11, 3, 'C','72704', '2016-09-20 20:35:15'),
    (12, 3,'D', '399606', '2016-09-20 20:44:35'),
    (13, 26,'A' ,'4456', '2016-09-20 20:49:45');
```

**Requirement:**

User has two search filters.

In first search filter he says, get me all the cars that have sourceId in (44,3) for certain date and time. Suppose ( e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:35:00' )

In second search filter he says, get me all the cars that have sourceId in (26,3,5) for another date and time. Suppose ( e.createdOn > '2016-09-20 20:36:00' and e.createdOn < '2016-09-20 20:49:00' )

**Now I want to get all (carNumbers, carCode) which are available in both search results.**

The query need to be fast since the real table contains over 300 million records.

so far below is the maximum i could go with the query (its not even producing valid results)

```
    select distinct e1.carNumber, e1.carCode from event e1  

    inner join (select e2.carNumber, e2.carCode from event e2 where e2.sourceId in (44,3) ) e3 on e1.carNumber= e3.carNumber 
    inner join (select e2.carNumber, e2.carCode from event e2  where e2.sourceId in (44,3)  ) e4 on e1.carCode= e4.carCode 

   inner join (select e2.carNumber, e2.carCode from event e2 where e2.sourceId in  (26,3,5) ) e5 on e1.carNumber= e5.carNumber 
    inner join (select e2.carNumber, e2.carCode from event e2  where e2.sourceId in  (26,3,5) ) e6 on e1.carCode= e6.carCode
```

I wonder if SQL is able to solve this question or should I use backend coding?

MySQL / MariaDB version in use:

mariadb-5.5.50

mysql-5.5.51

Comment: Why do you do 4 joins ? Do a where clause with your contraint. Each subquery will read the 300M. Meaning you read 5*300M lines.

Comment: Bascially I want to get intersected result of both search filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my guess from the reading of your condition

```
select distinct e1.carNumber, e1.carCode from event e1
    where e.sourceId in (44,3) 
    and e.createdOn = "certain date"
    and exists (
        select 'x' from event e2
            where e2.sourceId in (26,3,5) 
            and e2.createdOn = "another date" 
            and e1.carCode = e2.carCode
            and e1.carNumber = e2.carNumber
    )
```

Return all car from the first filter present from the select of the second filter

Read it one part at a time :

```
select distinct e1.carNumber, e1.carCode from event e1
    where e.sourceId in (44,3) 
    and e.createdOn = "certain date"
```

will return all car from the first filter. From that, we need to filter again with the second one.

```
select 'x' from event e2
        where e2.sourceId in (26,3,5) 
        and e2.createdOn = "another date" 
        and e1.carCode = e2.carCode
        and e1.carNumber = e2.carNumber
```

I use the `exists` clause to check if there is a result with the car already present in the first result.

EDIT 2 : last edit because you keep adding demands ...

```
select distinct e1.carNumber, e1.carCode from event e1
       inner join event e2 on  e1.carCode = e2.carCode and e1.carNumber = e2.carNumber and e2.sourceId in (26,3,5) and e2.createdOn = "another date"  --the second filter
       -- inner join event e3 on  e1.carCode = e3.carCode and e1.carNumber = e3.carNumber and e3.sourceId in (x,y,z) and e3.createdOn = "some crazy date" --the third filter ...
    where e.sourceId in (44,3)  and e.createdOn = "certain date" --the first filter
```

Comment: Both car number and car code should be matched for valid common result.

Comment: Can you please explain, why are you select 'x' in subquery.

Comment: How it is performing intersection of two results?

Comment: I understand your point. Can you please let me know if instead of two there are three search filters, how I will make this query dynamic?

Comment: Can you please edit and provide join solution? because later on we are planning to increase search filters. Thanks

Comment: where e.sourceId in (44,3)  and e.createdOn = "certain date"   and e2.sourceId in (26,3,5) and e2.createdOn = "another date", i think we need to replace and with or. Your thoughts?

Comment: Each join will do an intersection. You need the `AND` for this intersection. I reformated this query to be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. (and may not be exactly what you're after)

```
SELECT carnumber 
  FROM event 
 WHERE (sourceid IN (44,3) AND createdon BETWEEN  '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and '2016-09-20 20:35:00')
    OR (sourceid IN (26,3,5) AND createdon BETWEEN '2016-09-20 20:36:00' and  '2016-09-20 20:49:00')
 GROUP 
    BY carnumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: if one carnumber,carcode occurences are two times in sourceId = 44 it will bring its result but it should not bring because that car number is not available in sources (26,3,5), so intersection of two results is not done correctly.

Comment: in which case, a join will suffice

Comment: @Strawberry I did work on that way but doesn't seems to be ok for him.

Answer (score 0):

I used below query to solve my problem. Hope it helps others.

```
SELECT e1.carCode, e1.carNumber from event e1 

 WHERE (sourceid IN (44,3) AND createdon BETWEEN  '2016-09-20 20:24:00' and '2016-09-20 20:35:00')
    OR (sourceid IN (26,3,5) AND createdon BETWEEN '2016-09-20 20:36:00' and  '2016-09-20 20:49:00')

group by e1.carCode, e1.carNumber
having sum(e1.sourceId IN (44,3)) > 0 and
       sum(e1.sourceId IN (26,3,5)) > 0;
```